# AngularJS Comma separated for JSON format

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an issue with the comma separated with `ng-repeat` and `ng-if`.

I want to make the result as comma separated, but the last item is also include the `comma`.

My Expectation is : `AAA, CCC, EEE`

But the output is coming as : `AAA, CCC, EEE,`

The `ng-repeat` block is as below:

```
<div ng-repeat="provider in providersInfo">
    <span ng-repeat="policy in policiesInfo | filter:{ProviderId : provider.ProviderId }:true">
        <span ng-if="policy.HasChecked">{{ policy.PolicyName }}{{$last ? '' : ', '}}</span>
    </span>

    <!-- or -->

    <span ng-repeat="policy in policiesInfo | filter:{ProviderId : provider.ProviderId }:true">
        <span ng-if="policy.HasChecked">{{$index == 0 ? '' : ', '}}{{ policy.PolicyName }}</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Here, policiesInfo is join with lookup table, the output of `JSON` format is:

For each `ProviderId` it will contain 6 lookup records:

```
policiesInfo = [ 
    {PolicyId : 1, PolicyName: 'AAA', ProviderId: 25, HasChecked: true },
    {PolicyId : 2, PolicyName: 'BBB', ProviderId: 25, HasChecked: false },
    {PolicyId : 3, PolicyName: 'CCC', ProviderId: 25, HasChecked: true },
    {PolicyId : 4, PolicyName: 'DDD', ProviderId: 25, HasChecked: false },
    {PolicyId : 5, PolicyName: 'EEE', ProviderId: 25, HasChecked: true },
    {PolicyId : 6, PolicyName: 'FFF', ProviderId: 25, HasChecked: false }
]
```

Here `$last` is consider as `PolicyId : 6` and `$index` is consider as `PolicyId : 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your actual $last (FFF) is not rendered because it has `HasChecked: false`, so the last comma `","` you're seeing is the one rendered for EEE.

To achieve what you want you'd need to filter **out** the `HasChecked: false` first, so that $last would apply to the filtered array:

```
<span ng-repeat="policy in policiesInfo | filter: {HasChecked: true, ProviderId: provider.ProviderId}">
   {{policy.PolicyName}}<span ng-if="!$last">,</span>
</span>
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ozms2EHS3yPFB74mE5aU?p=preview)

Comment: I solved the issue by adding 1 more filter, but your answer helped me too think about the filter by **HasChecked**

Comment: Your suggestion <span ng-repeat="policy in policiesInfo | filter: {HasChecked: true, ProviderId: provider.ProviderId}"> is working.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved the result by adding one more filter:

```
<span ng-repeat="policy in policiesInfo | filter:{ProviderId : provider.ProviderId }:true | filter: checkedPolicies">
    <span>{{ insurancepolicy.PolicyTypeName }}{{$last ? '' : ', '}}</span>
</span>

$scope.checkedPolicies = function(policyItem) {
    return policyItem.HasChecked;
};
```

Comment: I forgot about your other filter - added it to the answer